# Как объединить две большие таблицы SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Объединить две большие таблицы в одну внешним джоином Oracle SQL, объединив по полю `COBILL` или `COBILLSERVICE`.

```
select count (bs.COBILLSERVICE),
       count (distinct b.cobill),
       count (distinct b.cocontract)
from bill b
left OUTER JOIN BILLSERVICE bs on b.COBILL = bs.COBILL
where bs.EXTERNALNUMBER >= 245491119 and bs.EXTERNALNUMBER <= 246278122 and b.COSOURCE = 2
```

```
select count (bs.COBILLSERVICE),
       count (distinct b.cobill),
       count (distinct b.cocontract)
from bill b
left OUTER JOIN BILLSERVICE bs on b.COBILL = bs.COBILL
where b.createdate > to_timestamp ('04.09.17 19:51:10,910000000', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:Mi:SS,FF')
and b.createdate < to_timestamp ('04.09.17 22:40:37,336000000', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:Mi:SS,FF')
and b.cosource = 2
```

Comment: По ним получаются разные результаты. Хочу узнать как сделать проверку, что поля не дублируются в CREATEDATE.

Comment: В первом запросе у Вас из-за наличия условий отбора по правой таблице во WHERE получается INNER JOIN - замените. PS. Что автору нужно, я так и не понял...

Comment: Есть подозрение, что автору просто нужна группировка по `b.createdate`.